# subscriber not throwing error if the publisher is down in zeromq

Tags: node.js, sockets, zeromq, publish-subscribe

Hi im writting a publisher and subscriber in nodejs using the zeromq below is my code

> publisher.js

```
var zmq = require('zmq')
var publisher = zmq.socket('pub')

publisher.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:7000', function(err) {
if(err)
    console.log(err)
else
    console.log("Listening on 7000...")
})


setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('sent');

    publisher.send("hi")
}, 1000)

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
publisher.close()
console.log('\nClosed')
})
```

> Subscriber.js

```
 var zmq = require('zmq')
 var subscriber = zmq.socket('sub')

 subscriber.on("message", function(reply) {
 console.log('Received message: ', reply.toString());
 })

 subscriber.connect("tcp://localhost:7000",function(err) {
 if (err) {
     console.log( 'Error binding socket' );
     return;
 }
 subscriber.close(); // This is fine! The socket is ready!
 })
 subscriber.subscribe("")

 process.on('SIGINT', function() {
 subscriber.close()
 console.log('\nClosed')
 })
```

When the publisher is down or the subscriber is down im trying to capture the error by writting a call back.But in both the cases the srror doesnt seem to be captured.I am stuck here dont know where am going wrong.Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ZeroMq does not raise errors when peers disconnect. The physical aspects of connect and disconnect are handled transparently and hidden from the application.

One way to force ZeroMq to raise an error if the peer is unavailable is with `ROUTER` and `router mandatory` option set to true. If ROUTER attempts to send to a peer that doesn't physically exist, `ROUTER` will raise an exception.